# How do i hide mounted drives from my desktop On Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu on wayland?

Tags: gnome

I have tried to look into the GNOME tweaks and tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts true
```

but it's not working I'm new to ubuntu any help?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept if by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you've got the ding (desktop icons next generation) gnome-shell extension installed... https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/

- right-click on the desktop
- select **Desktop Icons settings**
- review the following settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks! this was driving me crazy